# How can I check if the digits of a number are ordered ascending or descending whitout using strings or lists in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I want to use only integers and going only once throw the number!
I managed to solve this problem, using two methods, but I am trying to find a way to have only one method that checks any number, to see if it`s digits are ordered ascending, descending or are not ordered!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 0;
    System.out.println("Number: ");

    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);) {
        number = sc.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Numbers only!");
    }

    if (checkDigitsOrder(number)) {
        System.out.println("The digits are ordered descending!");
    } 
}

private static boolean checkDigitsOrder(int number) {
    int lastDigit, beforeLastDigit, clone = number;

    if (number == 0) {
        System.out.println("Number can`t be 0!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    lastDigit = clone % 10;
    clone /= 10;
    beforeLastDigit = clone % 10;
    clone /= 10;

    if (lastDigit < beforeLastDigit) {
        do {
            lastDigit = number % 10;
            number /= 10;
            beforeLastDigit = number % 10;
            number /= 10;

            if (lastDigit < beforeLastDigit) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println(number);
        } while (number > 0);
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your algorithm:

1. The problem has 3 possible states (ascending, descending and not ordered) and yet, your method returns a `boolean` (2 states).
2. It does not handle cases where you have equal and consecutive digits (`432111` should still be considered ascending, but `lastDigit < beforeLastDigit` would return `false` in your code).

So here is my suggestion: return an `int` (`1=ascending`, `-1=descending` and `0=not oredered`), and add a nested loop that effectively skips a cycle if `currentDigit` and `lastDigit` are the same:

```
public static int order(int num) {
    //fetch the first two digits
    int lastDigit = num%10, digit;
    num /= 10;
    digit = num%10;

    if(digit == 0) ???;//case where only one digit, handle it as you wish   

    while(digit==lastDigit) {
        lastDigit = digit;
        num /= 10;
        digit = num%10;
    }

    if(digit == 0) ???;//case where repeated digit, handle it as you wish   

    //is it ascending so far?
    boolean ascending = digit > lastDigit;

    while(num != 0) {
        lastDigit = digit;
        digit = num%10;

        while(digit==lastDigit) {
            lastDigit = digit;
            num /= 10;
            digit = num%10;
        }

        //this handles the case where the last digits are the same
        if(num == 0) break;

        //if not same direction, return 0 (not ordered)
        if(ascending != digit>lastDigit) return 0; 

        num /= 10;
    }

    if(ascending) return 1; //ascending
    else return -1; //descending
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new enum and use this methods:

```
private enum Order {
    ascending,
    descending,
    notOrdered
}
private static Order checkNumberOrder(int number) {
    int prevDigit = number % 10;
    int clone = number / 10;
    boolean ascending = false;
    boolean descending = false;
    while (clone > 0) {
        int currentDigit = clone % 10;
        if (currentDigit > prevDigit) {                
            if (ascending) {
                 return Order.notOrdered;
            }
            descending = true;
        else if (currentDigit < prevDigit) {                
            if (descending) {
                 return Order.notOrdered;
            }
            ascending = true;
        }
        prevDigit = currentDigit;
        clone = clone / 10;
    }
    if (descending) {
        return Order.descending;
    }
    if (ascending) {
        return Order.ascending;
    }
    return Order.notOrdered;
}
```

If all digit of `number` are equal, like this `1111`, the method will return `Order.notOrdered`, but if `number = 11112` the method will return `Order.ascending`
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I`m trying to use only integers.